# VBA to select columns by true/false condition

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT:
Both of the codes below are nearly perfect, but ultimately had the same issue. B1 and D1:E1 are properly grouped, but for some reason, the entire range of data, A1:E1 is also grouped. B1 and D1:E1 then function as subgroups, which is not ideal.

```
    |   A    |   B    |   C   |   D   |   E   |
-----------------------------------------------
 1  |  TRUE  |  FALSE |  TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
 2  |        |        |       |       |       |
 3  |        |        |       |       |       |
```

In my set of data, starting with B1, the first row has TRUE or FALSE. Ultimately, I am trying to group all columns that have FALSE. This is the code I have so far. The code runs, but it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions

```
Option Explicit

Sub hideColumns()

Dim falseColumnRange As Range
Dim grp2 As Range

Set falseColumnRange = GetFalseColumnRange(Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1)))

If Not falseColumnRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each grp2 In falseColumnRange.Areas 
        grp2.Columns.Group
    Next
End If

End Sub

Function GetFalseColumnRange(rng2 As Range) As Range
    Dim ColumnRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Object
    For Each Cell In rng2
      If Cell.Value = False Then
        Set ColumnRange = Range(Cell.Address)
    Else
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Your function `GetFalseColumnRange` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `GetFalseColumnRange` that will work:

```
Function GetFalseColumnRange(rng2 As Range) As Range
    Dim ColumnRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In rng2
        If Cell.Value = False Then
            If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then
                Set ColumnRange = Cell
            Else
                Set ColumnRange = Union(ColumnRange, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    Set GetFalseColumnRange = ColumnRange
End Function
```

When you use this function, note that blank cells will be coerced to `False`, so use with care. Otherwise the range that you grab might be too big.

Comment: This definitely helps. After I updated the code, the entire range, including TRUEs is grouped, and then the FALSEs are grouped separately. Any tips?

Comment: @MaineBlackBears I'm not sure what you mean. When I ran your code on some data I mocked up it worked as expected. False columns were grouped but true ones were left alone (nice bit of code, by the way). Perhaps you can edit your question with a data mockup which illustrates the problem (e.g. give a 4x5 array of values which corresponds to the range `A1:E4`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Edited above. Let me know if I can explain it better.

Comment: @MaineBlackBears I still can't reproduce your issue, but note that if the true/false values are in the first row, then that `Offset(1)` in `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1)` doesn't really make sense. Why shift to the second row? If it is blank -- then it is being coerced to False. Just drop `.Offset(1)` and see how it works.

Comment: That's it! Thank you you again.

Comment: @MaineBlackBears In my mockups I had data in the row below the TRUE/FALSE -- and that data coerced to TRUE, so I didn't realize the source of the problem at first.

Answer (score 1):

you have to:

- update `ColumnRange`  with a `Union()` method
- finally set `GetFalseColumnRange` to `ColumnRange` and return found range

  ```
  Function GetFalseColumnRange(rng2 As Range) As Range
      Dim ColumnRange As Range, cell As Range

      Set ColumnRange = rng2.Offset(1).Resize(1, 1) '<-- initialize ColumnRange with a "dummy" cell out of 'rng2' range
      For Each cell In rng2
          If Not cell.Value Then Set ColumnRange = Union(cell, ColumnRange) '<--| if current cell is False then add it to 'ColumnRange' range
      Next
      Set GetFalseColumnRange = Intersect(ColumnRange, rng2) '<--| get rid of the "dummy" cell
  End Function
  ```

Comment: This clearly works with the intended application (+1), but in general I think it a bit dicey to assume that an offset of a passed range is defined. What if you pass the function a range which contains a cell on the bottom row?

Comment: I chose to offset along the rows because there are much more of them than columns... Anyhow I wanted to show a way: if OP's case is such that he runs out of rows, then in can offset one column

Comment: It was a pedantic point on my part. It is annoying that `Union` doesn't work naturally when one of the ranges is empty. In math, (empty set) union S is just S. In VBA it is a run-time error.

Comment: Your comment helps people to better understand and had me give a more complete answer, so no pedantic at all! While I fully agree on the "annoying" behavior of VBA `Union()`